# Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)

Tags: memory, heroku, clojure

I have a Clojure web application I am running on a free plan on Heroku. The app has been working well for more or less one month, but in the last 3 days the logs have been showing up this error and the app is not working.

[image: Error from Heroku logs]

I am not able to reproduce this error locally, where everything starts up fine.

I tried restarting the app several times, deploying a new instance and fiddling around with JAVA_OPTS and JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS, but nothing has helped and I am stuck with the same errors.

The whole code for the application is [here](https://github.com/feychou/tsuki). Has anyone experience with this error and possible ways to work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the culprit of the exceeded memory.
The command run by Heroku on startup was not using the jar file. What I had before was `web: lein ring server-headless` and I changed it to execute the jar `web: java -jar target/<app-name>-standalone.jar` in the Procfile.

Since I am using [ring](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring), I also have Heroku run `lein ring uberjar` instead of `lein uberjar` before startup: this is as easy as setting `LEIN_BUILD_TASK='ring uberjar'` as a global config var in Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, the app consumes more memory than Heroku allocated for it. Heroku allows you to look at app metrics, graph from there might be useful for identifying the cause.

Heroku has a special guide for memory related problems in JVM application [java-memory-issues](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-memory-issues). You might find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your max heap size lower by running

```
$ heroku config:set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Xmx256m"
```

Comment: This does not seem to help in my specific case. Tried with a bunch of optimisations like these https://github.com/rogerallen/tweegeemee/blob/master/project.clj#L15-L20 but no success.

Comment: That probably means you have a lot of native memory. Read this https://jkutner.github.io/2017/04/28/oh-the-places-your-java-memory-goes.html